# Cite NumPy in BibTex

Tags: citations, bibtex

**How to cite [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) in BibTex?**

The [Scipy citing page](https://www.scipy.org/citing.html) recommends:

> Travis E, Oliphant. **A guide to NumPy**, USA: Trelgol Publishing, (2006).

Is it correct to use:

```
@Misc{numpy,
  author =    {Travis Oliphant},
  title =     {{NumPy}: A guide to {NumPy}},
  year =      {2006--},
  howpublished = {USA: Trelgol Publishing},
  url = "http://www.numpy.org/",
  note = {[Online; accessed <today>]}
 }
```

Or should I cite just SciPy?

#### Research Gate

On [Research Gate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/213877900_Guide_to_NumPy), the citation suggested is:

```
@book{book,
author = {Oliphant, Travis},
year = {2006},
month = {01},
pages = {},
title = {Guide to NumPy}
}
```

Or cite as a book?

Comment: Why is there a publisher if it is an online resource?

Comment: Also, there is a spurious "Numpy" in the title, and the capitalization is inconsistent.

Comment: As a formatting suggestion, rather than `misc`, maybe use `manual`?

Comment: @RichardErickson Could you give an example as an answer? And A guide to NumPy is a Book, maybe cite as a book? or manual?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni On the [BibTex doc](http://bib-it.sourceforge.net/help/fieldsAndEntryTypes.php), the `Misc` entry has a `howpublished` field: `How something strange has been published.`. I thought that the Online Manual could be on that field.

Comment: @danieltakeshi, You have the fields correct. A `books` or `manual` _may_ be formatted differently than `misc`. It depends upon your style file and where you are trying to publish. That venue's specific requirements may prefer one method over another.

Comment: Also, @cag51 has the correct answer to your question about _what_ to cite. Please consider re-marking that answer as correct. My comment is only about formatting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Looks right to me.** That's how they ask to be cited, and it seems reasonable. Indeed, [this discussion](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5482/how-do-i-reference-the-python-programming-language-in-a-thesis-or-a-paper) also agrees that citing the user manual is the right choice.

Comment: Note that this answer refers to the **first option** (`$Misc{...`) as correct.  The second option was added to the question **after** this answer was posted.

Answer (score 5):

As to 2020, Numpy now has a Nature paper https://numpy.org/citing-numpy/

```
@Article{         harris2020array,
 title         = {Array programming with {NumPy}},
 author        = {Charles R. Harris and K. Jarrod Millman and St{'{e}}fan J.
                 van der Walt and Ralf Gommers and Pauli Virtanen and David
                 Cournapeau and Eric Wieser and Julian Taylor and Sebastian
                 Berg and Nathaniel J. Smith and Robert Kern and Matti Picus
                 and Stephan Hoyer and Marten H. van Kerkwijk and Matthew
                 Brett and Allan Haldane and Jaime Fern{'{a}}ndez del
                 R{'{\i}}o and Mark Wiebe and Pearu Peterson and Pierre
                 G{'{e}}rard-Marchant and Kevin Sheppard and Tyler Reddy and
                 Warren Weckesser and Hameer Abbasi and Christoph Gohlke and
                 Travis E. Oliphant},
 year          = {2020},
 month         = sep,
 journal       = {Nature},
 volume        = {585},
 number        = {7825},
 pages         = {357--362},
 doi           = {10.1038/s41586-020-2649-2},
 publisher     = {Springer Science and Business Media {LLC}},
 url           = {https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-020-2649-2}
}
```

And if you use the new `biblatex-software` package, you can replace `@Article` by `@Software`

Comment: +1 from me. The [biblatex-software](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-software)'s `@Software` field is probably the way to go. You can include the actual versions or module, as well as the license.Highly recommended!

Answer (score 4):

The proposed citation seems correct. I found the same at http://www.citebay.com/how-to-cite/numpy/.

```
@book{oliphant2006guide, 
  title={A guide to NumPy}, 
  author={Oliphant, Travis E}, 
  volume={1}, 
  year={2006}, 
  publisher={Trelgol Publishing USA} 
}
```

Comment: Answer edited. Thank you for feedback.